# Complex RBAC Codeigniter Library (for fine grained users permissions and group based limits)

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-2, rbac

i am in the middle of a project that evolved in a direction that it require some sort of RBAC integrated with the authentication, but with advanced functionality (setting "caps" or "limits on users, based on their role/group). A SaaS site with paid and free plans like GitHub, Basecamp etc. can be a good example.

I already tested:

Ion Auth - http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Wolf Auth - http://github.com/Vheissu/Wolfauth---A-Codeigniter-Auth-Library

Perm Spark - http://getsparks.org/packages/perm/versions/HEAD/show

Codeigniter-RBAC - https://github.com/pdiddy/CodeIgniter-RBAC

and some other (one for all: Bonfire). Some of these have only authentication features, some lacks auth but provide RBAC. None of these makes use or mention about the possibility to have user limits.

I started developing a similar library myself (trying not to break Ion Auth function naming, because i am moving out from there), but, considering that i have only finished to plan the database schema and implement it in migrations, i think it is better to use something ready and tested (if it exists) instead of reinventing the wheel. Does anyone know a library to accomplish this particular tasks?

I am working with CI: 2.1.0 + HMVC, thinking to add DataMapper or RedBean for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Cant think of anything else right now except cibonfire. cibonfire provides Auth and RBAC both. Have been using for more than 2 years now.

Comment: I mentioned it in my question. Even Bonfire has no capabilities features builtin.

Comment: The feature you want is very easy to implement in bonfire. Couple of hours of work max.